# Need to update row at Postgres table with join by array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, join

my table schema looks this way:

```sql
create table table_with_arrays
(
    dim_col_code_array integer[] -- contains foreign keys to dict_table.array_code
    dim_col_val_array  varchar[] -- needs to be populated with dict_table.array_value
);

create table dict_table(
   array_code integer,
   array_value varchar
)
```

there is the field `dim_col_code_array` with values like `[10,300,400]`. these integers are foreign keys to `dict_table.array_code`.

For each row of `table_with_arrays` I need to join each value of dim_col_code_array with table `dict_table` by each element of `dim_col_code_array = integer.array_code`
And then store joined array_value in the same order to `table_with_arrays.dim_col_val_array`

Example:

```
table_with_arrays contains record:
[1,2,3], [/** fill me with values*/]

dict_table contains records
1 FIRST
2 SECOND
3 THIRD

query should update record of table_with_arrays to
[1,2,3], [FIRST, SECOND, THIRD]
```

is there any "smart" ideas / insights that I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join can be done using the operator `ANY` :

```
SELECT dim_col_code_array, array_agg(array_value ORDER BY array_code) as dim_col_val_array  
FROM table_with_arrays t
JOIN dict_table d ON d.array_code = ANY(t.dim_col_code_array)
GROUP BY dim_col_code_array
```

The update can be :

```
UPDATE table_with_arrays t
SET dim_col_val_array = sub_q.dim_col_val_array 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT dim_col_code_array, array_agg(array_value ORDER BY array_code) as dim_col_val_array  
    FROM table_with_arrays t
    JOIN dict_table d ON d.array_code = ANY(t.dim_col_code_array)
    GROUP BY dim_col_code_array
    ) AS sub_q
WHERE sub_q.dim_col_code_array = t.dim_col_code_array;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7FGUJeAO)

Comment: This orders by `array_code` *value*. But *"the same order"* requires to order by original *position* in `dim_col_code_array`.

Comment: Thanks, I've patched query, it preserves order.

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Unnest the array [`WITH ORDINALITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to remember the original order of array elements.
Then join to the lookup table and feed the ordered result to an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS).
Can be done in a correlated subquery:

```sql
UPDATE table_with_arrays t
SET   dim_col_val_array = ARRAY(
                           SELECT array_value
                           FROM   unnest(t.dim_col_code_array) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(array_code, ord)
                           JOIN   dict_table d USING (array_code)
                           ORDER  BY a.ord
                           );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h56giIal)

See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)